# How to change desktop (Xubuntu) appearance via terminal?

Tags: xubuntu

Always using dark mode isn't great either. A quick change using buttons in the taskbar would be interesting.

The system is Xubuntu (Ubuntu 23.04). The solutions you find don't work with this. Thanks for your ideas.

More information

More specifically, I want to switch very easily from Adwaita-Dark to Numix, from dark to light, and vice versa.

The most similar "solution" I found is this, but it can't work.

```
/usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Adwaita-Dark'
```

I just can't find anything better, but it has to work.

Comment: https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfconf/start   Your question is very *broad* and isn't specific as to what you want to change; "*change desktop appearance*" but don't say what specifically; and you state solutions found don't work? but not what part of [`xfconf-query`](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfconf/xfconf-query) you actually tried; or what you edited & how you edited it (`sed` etc)